# Why SegmentedControl opens in the reverse order?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
   [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.segmentedControl removeAllSegments];
    s = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in self.top.segments) {
        [_segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:dictionary [@"sTitle"] atIndex:s animated:NO];
        self.bioTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dictionary [@"sData"]];
    }}
```

My segmentedControl start in reverse order. Please if anyone knows, tell me how to solve this problem?
Please see the example in the video:
http://youtu.be/YSYFxvb7fpA

Comment: Thank you, but nothing change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added new segment always at index 0, i.e. at the beginning.

So you are getting like:

```
A

B>A

C>B>A
```

You need to add at the end.

Use:

```
s = 0;
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in self.top.segments) {
    [_segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:dictionary [@"sTitle"] atIndex:s animated:NO];
    self.bioTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dictionary [@"sData"]];
    s++;
}
```